# In a regular polygon, what is the distance between two "adjacent-but-one" vertices?

Tags: trigonometry

Consider a regular polygon with $n$ sides, each of length $1$.

The distance between any two adjacent vertices is, of course, just $1$.

But what is the distance between any two "adjacent-but-one" vertices? (That is, two vertices that have exactly one other vertex between them.)

Is there any general way to find this? (I know that this is $2\cos \pi/n$ but I was hoping to express this distance solely in terms of $n$ and without using any trigonometric functions.)

---

For example, in the case of the pentagon ($n=5$), we can find that it's $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. So I was wondering if there are more general methods for finding the same for bigger $n$.

Comment: You say yourself that the exact answer involves the sin function. Why should we expect that expression to equal something that doesn't involve a trigonometric function?

Comment: You can simplify the expression to $2\cos\frac\pi n$.

Comment: Would you prefer an infinite series to a trig function? or an infinite continued fraction? or a complex exponential function? I think those are your choices.

Comment: If $n=2^k$ the cosine mentioned by "user" can be expressed by a nested radical, without the trig.

Comment: You always can give a polynomial equation for the value, but I wouldn't expect it always to have a closed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is negative.

The numbers $\cos\dfrac\pi n$ are known to be the solutions of equations of the form

$$T_n(x)=-1$$ where $T_n$ is a polynomial (more precisely a Chebyshev polynomial). For instance, $\cos\dfrac\pi7$ is a root of $$64c^7-112c^5+56c^3-7c=-1.$$

It is known from the Abel-Ruffini theorem that such roots are not expressible in radicals (i.e. with addition/multiplication/exponents), and we cannot avoid a trigonometric function.

Comment: Not 65 but 64 in the leading coefficient, and this particular polynomial can be solved with radicals.  The radicals are, however, irredeemably complex.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: yep, my bad. Isn't solvability related to the prime Fermat numbers ?

Comment: Polynomial equations for trigonometric functions of rational numbers times $\pi$ are always radical solvable; they have the right Galois groups for such solvability.  However, to get _real_ radicals and geometric constructibility you need a number of sides whose totient is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can work out the distance to the $k$th next vertex. Working in the complex plane, take the vertices to be $r\exp\frac{2ik\pi}{n},\,0\le k\le n-1$. Since$$\left|\exp\frac{2ik\pi}{n}-1\right|=\left|\exp\frac{ik\pi}{n}-\exp\frac{-ik\pi}{n}\right|=2\sin\frac{k\pi}{n},$$length-$1$ sides require $r=\frac12\csc\frac{\pi}{n}$, so the general distance is$$2r\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}=\frac{\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}.$$(We can also do this without complex numbers, using the cosine rule with some angle-chasing.) You want the $k=2$ distance, which is$$\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}.$$We can't get rid of the trigonometry in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We actually can always reduce the trigonometric expressions to radicals.  However, only for a limited set of cases is this reduction of any real use.

There is no general formula for the radical expression.  Generally the form of the radical expression varies from polygon to polygon, roughly following these rules based on geometric construction:

- Where there are higher order radicals, we need more complex tools.  An unmarked straightedge and compasses are sufficient for square roots, marking the straightedge or using a tomahawk for angle trisection makes the cube roots appearing in these radical possible (but no seventh roots and probably not all fifth roots), and so on with increasing complexity for higher order radicals.
- When radicals are nested multiple steps are needed in the construction assuming you have the right tools (see above); more layers of nesting means a more complex procedure.

With these rules in mind we can render the diagonal/side ratios below for regular polygons up to twelve sides:

Triangle:  $1$ (the "diagonal" is just the third side)

Quadrilateral/Square:  $\sqrt{2}$

Pentagon:  $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$

Hexagon:  $\sqrt{3}$

Heptagon:  $(1/3)(1+\sqrt[6]{28}(\sqrt[3]{1+3i\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{1-3i\sqrt{3}}))$

Octagon:  $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$

Enneagon:  $\sqrt[3]{(1/2)(1+i\sqrt{3})}+\sqrt[3]{(1/2)(1-i\sqrt{3})}$

Decagon:  $\sqrt{(5+\sqrt{5})/2}$

Hendecagon:  A combination of complex fifth roots, too unwieldy for here.

Dodecagon:  $(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)/2$

The sixth root in the expression for the heptagon is basically a square root and a cube root, so by the first of my rules this expression corresponds to a polygon constructible with a straightedge, compasses and an angle trisector.  The nine-sided figure requires similar tools.  For both of these cases note that the cube roots are accompanied by complex arguments.  This is because [multiple real roots in a cubic or higher degree equation cannot be rendered solely by real radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).  Clearly the complex radicals make these forms impractical for computational use; they would have to be exchanged for trigonometric functions again to get things in terms of real variables.  The hendecagon involves a complicated combination of fifth roots, beyond the capabilities of an angle trisector but still constructible by a peculiar method with the aid of a marked straightedge.

The other cases shown above (3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 or 12 sides) involve classically constructible polygons with relatively simple procedures, and they are basically the only cases where the use of radical expressions is practical.